# Bringing Internet Explorer window to foreground

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, visibility

I have a macro that opens the Internet Explorer

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
```

Later the macro interacts with other windows, so the IE loses the focus.

But, after the other interactions, I need to send keys to the IE application. I searched how to activate again the IE Window, but none worked.

I tried (1)

```
Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Public Sub test()
  Set acObj = GetObject(, "InternetExplorer.Application")
  SetForegroundWindow acObj.hWndAccessApp
End Sub
```

(2)

```
Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Public Sub test()
  Dim IE As Object
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  'code
  SetForegroundWindow IE.hWndAccessApp
End Sub
```

(3)

```
IE.Focus 'or IE.Document.Focus
```

(4)

```
AppActivate("exactly_name_of_the_window")
```

Comment: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24141365/How-do-I-activate-bring-to-front-an-internet-explorer-window-in-VBScript.html

Answer (score 7):

This is more of a *hack* than anything. Basically, you will hide it then immediately unhide it.

You could try this Sub:

```
Sub ieBringToFront(ieObj As InternetExplorer) ' or (ieObj As Object) --> Late Binding

    With ieObj
        .Visible = False
        .Visible = True
    End With

End Sub
```

You would use it like this example:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer

    ' Addt'l Code

    ' IE Obj loses focus here

    ieBringToFront ie

End Sub
```

> [image]

Comment: This is so simple... Yet so brilliant.

Comment: @K.Davis That is simple and a good idea. But, i tried it today and it didn't work. I think it's because i'm calling the macro from a batch vbs file (i need to do this because i use the task manager on windows to run the macro daily through the vbs file). When i run the macro directly, it did work. Don't know how to fix it